# How to properly convert QValidator* to QDoubleValidator*

Tags: qt, casting

In this piece of code, edit_sclratio is a QLineEdit. How do I use it's validator as a QDoubleValidator without using an old-style cast:

```
(QDoubleValidator*)_ui->edit_sclratio->validator() //This works fine
```

But I want to use proper casting and static, dynamic, const and reinterpret cast doesn't work. The error is always it "casts away qualifiers.

```
QDoubleValidator* validator = static_cast<QDoubleValidator*>(_ui->edit_sclratio->validator());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error is always it "casts away qualifiers.

Here, it's talking about **const** qualifiers.

`QLineEdit::validator()` returns a `const QValidator*`, so you must cast it to a `const QDoubleValidator*`.

**Note**: I suggest you form the habit of using [`qobject_cast<>`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) for classes that inherit `QObject` (like `QValidator`). It has the added benefit of returning a `nullptr` if you try to cast to the wrong type; this lets you do run-time error checks.